# This regex won't work if there are spaces

Tags: regex

Regex is not really my thing. But i have this in my php file and have found it wont work if the string passed has any spaces. Can someone offer an amendment please.

regex:

```
preg_match('/^(\S+)\/\d/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);
$product_name = $matches[1];
```

the string will always be in the form of:

```
1productname/1.0.9 Sparkle/2
```

everything after the forward slash remains constant
before the forward slash can change, and this is the portion i am looking for.

i have found if the first portion contains spaces like:

```
1 product name/1.0.9 Sparkle/2
```

this will break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `/^(.+?)\/\d/`

If you weren't trying to match the value after, try this: `/^(.+?)\//`

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I went with this one as it was the closest to the existing code.

Answer (score 1):

The regex specifically checks for non-space characters (`\S`). Since you asked no question I'll stay content with giving you this explanation.

And it makes sense too. It's pretty reasonable to expect space-separated list of something/numbers signatures in user agent string. And even though they're often also separated by semicolons, it makes no sense to treat space as a part of match.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
^(.+?)/
```

This should capture your first portion.

Answer (score 0):

How about `/(.*?)/` if you only want to parse *1productname/**1.0.9 Sparkle**/2*, you begin searching for a forward slash, then you read everyting that comes between the first forward slash and the second one.

Or `^(.*?)/` if you only want to read ***1productname***/1.0.9 Sparkle/2, space or not space